# Weird icons in Wygwam

Tags: wygwam

I updated Wygwam to the most recent version (3.3.3) and now the icons in the toolbar all got messed up. I tried re-uploading the themes folder, and emptying the cache, but no luck so far.

[image: A screenshot from the toolbar]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the image was still in the Nexcess CDN cache. I forgot to purge that one.

Answer (score 0):

EE version? And do you have a custom theme? What accessories do you have installed? They can inject CSS/JS into your CP pages.

Using Chrome or Firefox, right click on one of the mal-positioned icons, and look at the CSS rulesets applied to the icon. See what CSS asset file is messing with your icon elements.

Answer (score 0):

don't just overwrite on the upgrade. Delete everything from the theme directory, then clear the cache, then try to load an entry page with Wygwam, then reupload the files and refresh the page